# Algebra Problem: Division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone help me with a problem involving the expression $$\frac{(2x^3-3x^2+b)}{(4-x^2)}?$$

The question is to find which values $b$ can be to simplify the expression, but I do not know how to begin.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: First, notice that $4-x^2=(2+x)(2-x)$. Then, if it can be simplified, $(2x^3-3x^2+b)$ must have factor $(2+x)$ or $(2-x)$, i.e. it vanishes when $x=2$ or $x=-2$.

Comment: I guess it depends on how simplified you want it to be. Do you want it simplified to a fraction or otherwise?

Comment: @Chiranjeev I have gotten it down to (2x^3−3x^2+b)(4−x2)=2x-3+(8x+12+b/(2+x)(2-x))

Comment: The question is to find what values of b we kan use to simplify the expression.

Comment: The expression you have got is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$4-x^2=-(x-2)(x+2)$, so you are looking for values of $b$ that make $2x^3-3x^2+b$ divisible by either $(x-2)$ or $(x+2)$.

So if you substitute $x=2$ into $2x^3-3x^2+b$ it will be 0, and the same for $x=-2$. This give you two simple equations in $b$, which gives you two values for $b$.

For $x=2$, you get $b=-4$, so you would expect $2x^3-3x^2-4$ to be divisible by $x-2$. You can check this by doing the division:
$2x^3-3x^2-4=(x-2)(2x^2+x+2)$.
So the expression simplifies to
$-\frac{2x^2+x+2}{x+2}$

Try this with $2x^3-3x^2+28$ and $(x+2)$, and you'll see that it works out.

Comment: How did you get there? And i get that b is either 4 or 32. How do i simplify with those answers?

Comment: By the way..is it $x^2-4$ or $4-x^2$??

Comment: $b$ is -4 or 28. So if you substitute, you get $2x^3-3x^2-4$ which will be divisible by $x-2$, and $2x^3-3x^2+28$, which will be divisible by $x+2$

Comment: @tatan, that's just a factor of -1, so it doesn't effect the division, just the sign. I'll fix my answer though.

Comment: But why do you divide by only x-2 or x+2 and not the whole 4-x^2?

Comment: In general you can only divide by $4-x^2$ if you can divide by its factors, ie $(x-2)$ and $(x+2)$, so you need only look for those factors.

Comment: It's analogous to searching for numbers divisible by 6. You find even numbers (divisible by 2) that are also divisible by 3. In this case you're searching just for simplification so you find divisible by 2 or 3, instead of 2 and 3.  If it happens to be both then you're lucky, but if it's not divisible by either 2 or 3 it will definitely not be divisible by 6...

Comment: I get the answers: 2x^2+x+2 V 2x^2-7x+14. I s it correct to say: The expression (2x^3−3x^2+b)/(4−x^2) can be simplified when the value of b is -4 V 28. Then it can be simplified to 2x^2+x+2 when b is -4 V 2x^2-7x+14 when b is 28.

Comment: Almost. You haven't got rid of both factors, so the full expression is $-(2x^2+x+2)/(x+2)$ in one example

Comment: Why is the factor still there? I thought when we divided by x+2 V x-2, that we got rid of it? Is it because we divide by the other one, so one is still there? And why is the answer negative in your example?

Comment: For 2x^3−3x^2+28 and (x+2) i get the answer (2x^2-7x+14)/(x-2)                      Do i put the original equal −(2x^2+x+2)/(x+2) times (2x^2-7x+14)/(x-2) or how does the original correspond with the two new answers?

Comment: There are two separate cases, which you need to keep independent. Case 1: $b=-4$, which I've worked out in my answer above, and case 2: $b=28$, which you have worked out I think. In each case you need to substitute $b$ into the original expression, and simplify by dividing top and bottom by $(x-2)$ or $(x+2)$. That's all there is to do for this question.

Comment: But i still have x-2 or x+2 left i the expression. And how do i formulate the answer?

Comment: No. It's not possible to get the top to be divisible by $(4-x^2)$, so you're always going to have a denominator. The problem is too constrained to solved both at once with just $b$.

Comment: Ok. So how do i formulate the answer? I know now that b=-4Vb=28 and that the denominator has the zeros (by the abc-formula) x=-2/x=2. And i also now the two answers we get with those numbers, but how do i formulate the answer? For example does thos work?                           When the value of b is either -4 or 28 it is possible to simplify the expression. Either to :−(2x^2+x+2)/(x+2) or to: (2x^2-7x+14)/(x-2).             But i still sont know why the first answer is negative

Comment: They're both negative. The original expression is divided by $-(x^2-4)$, so you just have to be careful when you're simplifying

Comment: So 4-x^2=-(x^2-4)=-(x-2)(x+2)? Thank you very much for all your help. You have been very helpful.

Comment: My pleasure! You've got it. Great persistence. That's the key!